# Unity Rotation Thrown Off After Starting Game?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out how to orient my model. I noticed the problem when I ran into trouble getting my character to rotate in the direction of movement. After significant trial and error with functions like LookAt() I realized it was because my character's z axis (forward vector) was not facing the same forward direction of the character. After rectifying this in Blender I imported into Unity and walah the z axis is in the same direction as the character. But when I play the game and the animation starts, the z axis points in the wrong direction again! Any idea why Unity is doing this? fyi I modeled the 3d object in blender.

[image]

AFter starting the game (character doesnt face z axis) :
[image]

Before starting the game (character faces z axis)

Comment: My best guess is something else in your code is controlling this but your question is so vague I can't begin to diagnose the problem try narrowing your search,provide more details what have you tried,ect and maybe throw in some relevant code

Comment: "Lookat" causes it to do just that so if the point  you pick is the other persons feet they will fall forwards, and then if you rotate they rotate around that offskew line.

Comment: same like @CoderJoe said. Also you can deactivate all your own scripts, that effect your Gameobject and hit the play button..

Comment: I have deactivated all my scripts and the problem continues. I am guessing the problem is the animation is on the wrong axis like @Immorality said.

Answer (score 0):

If your scene is modified when starting the game you can assume that it's logic you've created, likely scripts, that affect the Game Objects.

Like the comments suggest, try disabling the script components on your game objects to see what causes it.

---

Sometimes you may want this logic in your editor scene, so that your Objects are rotated the way they will be when the game starts even when you're working with the scene.

Imagine having a top-down game with a camera that follows the player and is always rotated towards the Player. You'd want this camera to rotate towards the player when you move it around, re-arranging it so that it gets the perfect angle. To achieve this you may use [[ExecuteInEditMode]](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ExecuteInEditMode.html):

```
[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class LookAtPlayer {
    Transform player;

    void Update() {
        this.transform.LookAt(player);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have re-imported your model and adjusted it's X/Y/Z axis while already having created an animation, then it is very likely that your animation is using the wrong Axis.

You can either copy the values of your animation onto the correct axis, or if the animation isn't very complex I advise you to recreate the animation from scratch.